# JSON to DataContract with = Symbol

Tags: json

I am unable to convert the following JSON into DataContract Class:

```
{"SomeData":"Sample={"Id":-1,"Key":"test"}"}
```

The error shown is:

```
After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: I. Path 'SomeData', line 1, position 22."
```

Please let me know if it is possible to convert this JSON data into the DataContract class?

Comment: The text highlighting should give you a hint, you can't have double quotes inside quotes `Id`, `Key`, and `test` are the only items **not** in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use single quotes inside `"Sample={ ... }"`:

```
{ "SomeData": "Sample={'Id':-1,'Key':'test'}" }
```

If you need them to be double quotes, you can escape them with `\"`

```
{ "SomeData": "Sample={\"Id\":-1,\"Key\":\"test\"}" }
```